# Reveal Jquery Popup On Page Load

Tags: jquery, plugins, popup, modal-dialog

I have read through the answers for this question which has been asked previously, but I cannot get it to work.

I have a website which uses the reveal popup on a click of a link, this works perfectly fine, but on a certain page I want the popup to activate on page load. I have no real background with jquery so please be patient and thorough :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you would do it when the dom (document object model) is ready, the *page* has been constructed and it's now safe to manipulate it, to *know* when that happens you should do something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('div#popup').fadeIn(200);
});
```

`$(function() { })` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { })`.

More info: http://api.jquery.com/ready/, http://learn.jquery.com/.